# VSCode Javascript/Typescript namespaces in hover

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am relatively new to typescript ( approx. one month ). Whilst coding, and hovering over a code snippet to figure how it works, it appears as such :
[VSCode Hover Documentation with `puppeteer` namespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QZiu.png)

( Sidenote : I do not know what most of anything is called, so I am just going to call the VSCode feature "VSCode Hover Documentation" )

Due to working on older javascript projects, I remembered that the VSCode Hover Documentation didn't have the namespace in it ( E.g. the hover doc was `...options?: LaunchOptions...` and not `...options?: puppeteer.LaunchOptions...` ) Going back to a couple of other projects to confirm my recollections prove me otherwise. Jumping from a typescript project and a javascript project with the `puppeteer` package on both results in both giving me the same result as specified earlier. On both projects, `puppeteer` is imported the same way via `require("puppeteer")`. I attempted the same procedure with `import`, but no dice.

Is there any settings in VSCode or `tsconfig.json` where I can achieve the [VSCode Hover Documentation without `puppeteer` namespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu1wX.png)? ( photo was edited to simulate desired effect )

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Images of code are frowned upon here because the code can't be tested by other SO contributors. You are much more likely to get help if you copy / paste both examples of code into two code blocks using the provided feature _ Please visit SO Help Center section on 'Asking' and specifically this post >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

There's no options or preferences to customize those tooltips.

But the thing is, those types *are* in the `puppeteer` namespace. This hint helps you know that. If you had your own type named `LaunchOptions`, then this tells you that type is different from that. It also gives you a hint about how to import that type.

So the namespace is there for a reason. Removing it would make things more confusing or ambiguous.